# Connection URL include name and password

Tags: android, http, url, okhttp

i want connect to url like this "http://192.168.10.xxx/eng..."

and in browser, i can pass by "http:admin:admin@192.168.10.xxx"

but when i use android okhttp and connect url

it always response unAuthenticated

i use many api to test,but not have fix it

who can i fix it...please hep me

thanks very much

```
   OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();
    String url = "http://192.168.10.254/eng/admin/siteSurvey.cgi";
    Request request = new Request.Builder().url(url).build();
    client = new OkHttpClient.Builder()
            .authenticator(new Authenticator() {
                @Override
                public Request authenticate(Route route, Response response) throws IOException {
                    System.out.println("Authenticating for response: " + response);
                    System.out.println("Challenges: " + response.challenges());
                    String credential = Credentials.basic("admin", "admin");
                    return response.request().newBuilder()
                            .header("Authorization", credential)
                            .build();
                }
            })
            .build();
    Call call = client.newCall(request);
    call.enqueue(new Callback() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call call, Response response) {
            String json = null;
            try {
                json = response.body().string();

            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            Log.d("OKHTTP", json);
        }
        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call call, IOException e) {

        }
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

The wiki has an example in the Recipes

https://github.com/square/okhttp/wiki/Recipes#handling-authentication

```
client = new OkHttpClient.Builder()
    .authenticator(new Authenticator() {
      @Override public Request authenticate(Route route, Response response) throws IOException {
        System.out.println("Authenticating for response: " + response);
        System.out.println("Challenges: " + response.challenges());
        String credential = Credentials.basic("jesse", "password1");
        return response.request().newBuilder()
            .header("Authorization", credential)
            .build();
      }
    })
    .build();
```

And there are examples in stackoverflow as well.

Comment: Yuri Schimke,thank you answer , i try to use this matheod ,
but sever response me 401,i have update my code,
can pleasr you tell me where i should fix?thank.